# Failed to resolve module specifier "sortablejs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to resolve module specifier "sortablejs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

This is my JS code below:

```
/*===== DRAG and DROP =====*/
import Sortable from "sortablejs";

const dropItems = document.getElementById('drop-items')

new Sortable(dropItems, {
    animation: 350,
    chosenClass: "sortable-chosen",
    dragClass: "sortable-drag"
});
```

I am trying to use the drag and drop with sortable .

Comment: You have to use a bundler to get the node modules in the browser. Check out `vite` or `webpack`

Answer (score 1):

[`sortablejs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sortablejs) is a dependency, you need to either install it with a package manager like `npm` or `yarn`, or if you are running your code directly in the browser, you can use an [import map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap) by adding the below elements to your html page:

```html
<script type="importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "sortablejs": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/sortablejs@1.15.0",
  }
}
</script>
<script type="module">
import Sortable from "sortablejs";

const dropItems = document.getElementById('drop-items')

new Sortable(dropItems, {
    animation: 350,
    chosenClass: "sortable-chosen",
    dragClass: "sortable-drag"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Import maps are really cool, but I don't think Safari supports them yet.